# Java - вопрос по парсингу (Selenium)

Tags: java, html, парсер, selenium

С помощью Selenium на Java пишу программу, которая заполняет некоторые поля, нажимает submit и т.д. Все шло нормально, пока не натолкнулся на такую вещь. В одно из полей мне нужно вставить текст. Делал я это так:

```
//Ищем ID поля ввода email и устанавливаем туда значение
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("vasya.antonov0274@gmail.com");
```

Столкнулся с полем, в которое мне нужно ставить значение, но которое не имеет прямого ID. Привожу код этого блока:

```
<div id="input-url">URL:
<div class="errorbox-good">
<input name="urlnt" value="" size="25" maxlength="1000" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

Значение мне нужно вставить в `<input name="urlnt" value="" size="25" maxlength="1000" type="text">`.
Знаю, что в selenium, кроме поиска по ID, есть методы поиска по имени тега и т.д. но перебрал разные варианты, пока ответа не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найдите по атрибуту `name`

```
driver.findElement(By.name("urlnt")).sendKeys("<TEXT>");
```

Как вариант `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#input-url .errorbox-good input")).sendKeys("<TEXT>");
```